# Update Laravel 4 to newer version by using composer

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4, and for example, there is a new version. Let say, Laravel 4.2. Can I update Laravel 4 by setting **composer.json** and using **composer command**? I don't want to configure its files manually when there is a newer version.

composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*@dev"
    },
```

in cmd:

```
composer update
```

Is it the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, although you also [need to check the official documentation and follow the official upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade), as there are still a couple of files you might need to change manually depending upon what version you are upgrading from.